# Data design: What's the best way to store tasks generated by a scheduler?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

this is a data design problem I am facing right now.

So I am currently designing a scheduling application for a farm. To deal with orders coming in, I've designed the following class called `Forecast`. Forecast has the following attributes:

1. Due_date
2. Entries - This is a list of `{crop:X, quantity:Y}` which indicates how much of each crop is required for each of these crop.

As you know, each crop has different durations for:

1. Propagation Duration (from seed to planting)
2. Spacing Duration (from planted to more spaced out for maximum sunlight)
3. Storage Duration (from harvest to expiry)

I wrote a "backward scheduler" which figures out when an order has to be met, then goes backwards and creates task for what needs to be done on what date.

[image]

Note that these calendar "entries" are not stored in the database - I generate them on the fly and am planning to allow my users to drag these events forward and backward depending on their preference.

Now, I am tasked with generating reports for each day on what needs to be done. My users would like to be able to generate a list of tasks for a particular date. (So if you look at my screenshot May 1st would result in one tasks being created, 'transplanting 12 units of Minutina').

I am not sure what's the best way to go about accomplishing this. My initial design is:

1. Create a table for tasks. This will include: (forecast_id, forecast_updated_at)
2. Store the tasks generated by my scheduler into this table.
3. When a user modifies a task, the database entry will be updated correspondingly.
4. However, if the user has decided to modify the original `Forecast`, then we will have to delete all the tasks associated with this forecast and regenerate a new sets of tasks and store them again in the table mentioned above.

The purpose of the (forecast_id, forecast_updated_at) is to allow me to quickly verify the correctness of the tasks currently in my database.

This design is a little messy and I would like to hear from any experts out there for a better approach to this problem.